# Font-smoothing in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, google-font-api

I have two websites using the same Google font (Rokkitt). One is WordPress. One is Asp.Net MVC. In WordPress the font looks great. In the Asp .Net site, it looks terrible. Highly pixelated.

Is there something I am missing about how to use google font. I'm just linking to the font in the page header.

Comment: Have you tried to use Inspect Element to see what the rendered pages are doing differently? Perhaps WordPress is using something like SIFR to render special fonts in Flash for compatibility with old browsers that don't support webfonts.

Comment: As far as I can tell its not doing anything special. Here is the WP site where the fonts look OK: http://stage3productions.com/

Comment: Without actually seeing the site where the error occurs we can only guess. Seeing the one without the error does not really help. Maybe it has something to do with [font smoothing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264(v=vs.85).aspx) but it is impossible to tell.

Comment: You could see this thread about fonts not rendering properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692151/fonts-are-not-rendered-correctly-in-release-mode-but-is-working-on-debug-mode-i?answertab=votes#tab-top